# How to get linux process id alone using perl

Tags: perl

When i execute the below command in command prompt it works fine. but when i include the same in perl script, it shows the whole process name.

```
ps -ef | grep truecontrol | awk '{print$2}'
```

returns

```
4567
3456
```

When I execute it throught perl, it shows the whole process details. I want to assign it to a variable array and work on it. Let me know how to do it?

```
my $process_chk_command = `ps -ef | grep truecontrol | awk '{print$2}'`;
print($process_chk_command);


root      9902  9890  0 05:50 ?        00:00:03 /opt/abc/jre/bin/java -DTCFTP=1 -d64 -Xms16m -Xmx64m -Djava.library.path=/opt/abc/server/ext/wrapper/lib -cla
```

Comment: Of course, the [proper](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) way to write that is `ps -ef | awk '/truecontrol/{print$2}'` or just run `ps -ef` and do the filtering in Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

perl's [backticks and qx//](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) interpolate variables, so when you write:

```
my $process_chk_command = `ps -ef | grep truecontrol | awk '{print $2}'`;
```

perl interpolates the [special variable `$2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).  In your case, `$2` is not set, and thus expands to the empty string, so the *awk* command is simply `{print}`.

You could escape the dollar sign (`` `ps ... | awk '{print \$2}'` ``) to avoid this.

(As an aside, I'd recommend `grep [t]ruecontrol` to prevent *grep* from matching its own process table entry, or that of its parent shell which constructs the pipeline.  *sh* aficionados with a POSIX bent might additionally suggest `` `ps -eo pid,comm,args | awk '/[t]ruecontrol/{print \$1}'` ``.)

Answer (score 5):

Try using `pgrep`

```
my $process_chk_command = `pgrep truecontrol`;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $process_chk_command = `ps -ef | grep truecontrol`;

my (undef,$pid) = split(' ', $process_chk_command, -1);
```

ps, there's a perl utility that converts awk scripts to perl: [a2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html)

Answer (score 0):

True to Perl's motto, another way:

```
my $pcc=`killall -s truecontrol`;
my (undef,undef,$pid)=split(' ',$pcc);
print $pid;
```